# Execute SQL Query every 50ms in the loop

Tags: mysql, database

Is it bad to execute MySQL query every 50ms in the loop?

For example:

```
while(1) {
    sleep(0.05)
    $bool = do_check();
    if ($bool) { ... }
}

function do_check() {
  $sql1 = "select .... ";
  $sql2 = "select .... ";

  some maths formula;

  return true for false; 
}
```

It is a Call Centre product I am developing. It has to check how many agents are free and how many calls is dialled and then make a decision to dial more calls or not through API.

Comment: whats the context - why would you think you need to query every 50ms ?

Comment: Isn't it better to invoke a function when an agent status is changed to free? It's not smart to continuously check who is free. If you have an agent table with agent status, you can simply create a trigger that lets you know when agent status has changed.

Comment: @John Do you mean like Event detection when agents are free then execute SQL query?

Comment: Do you (your code) update agent's status when they receive a call or is it updated by some other process that you can't interact with?

Comment: @N.B. Well on the UI agent can manually change state to "Not Available" or "Available" (free) which then update to the database. If Available state is selected then the process will start making calls - If call is Answered (detected by Events) then Agent state will be changed automatically to "TALKING" - update of agent state will be done in MYSQL. I am thinking doing variable  boolean to detect if Events is received via socket (PBX) - if detected than execute SQL - see example: http://pastebin.com/yPxzdrHm if there is a better solution I be glad to hear :)

Comment: @N.B. Note: There are many concurrent companies and campaigns at the same time then I need parallel execution of code for every set of agents.

Comment: So what you're saying is that everyone and everything works with **one** database, right?

Comment: @N.B. Yea there will be a table called company. it is a web base call centre and company can sign up to use the system.

Comment: So if there's 1 database in question, where is the problem? An agent makes themselves available / unavailable or an event does so. That means a table holds the information. When you need to check who is "free", you read from that table. At that point in time, everyone who are free are available for the talk. I don't even see why you would need to query every 50ms. You have the insert, update and delete done by you. Every time you do any of those actions, you know who is free or isn't free. Concurrency is handled by MySQL anyway. Why complicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it would be better to use a database trigger that will notify your application when the specific condition you want to monitor change status, to implement a similar strategy you need a trigger that will call an User Defined function in MySQL that will call your application through an interprocess communications system (eg. Socket, JMS message) .

Take a look at [this site](http://www.mysqludf.org) for some example of MySQL UDF.

Comment: What about using Events detection from PBX Server, if Events are received then boolean  is set to true which then execute SQL For example: http://pastebin.com/yPxzdrHm

Comment: It could be an option too.

Comment: There are many concurrent companies and campaigns at the same time then I need parallel execution of code for every set of agents. I am not sure if using global variables as a flag is a good idea. Is there alternative?

Comment: You could use an hash map with companies as key instead of using global variables flags ...